# Allowing one column to be edited but not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have an asp.net c# application.

my gridview has a datasource that has 2 fields.

1 field cannot be edited by the user, but i need the other one to be editable!

is this possible to do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the `ReadOnly="true"` property on all that you don't want editable.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.readonly.aspx

A quick example from that page

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    autogenerateeditbutton="true"
    allowpaging="true" 
    datakeynames="CustomerID"  
    runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" readonly="true" headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" readonly="true" headertext="Customer Name"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="ZIP Code"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

In this case **CustomerID** and **Company** name are read only and can't change. **Address**, **City** and **PostalCode** can be edited.

Just set the ReadOnly option to true on the columns you DON'T want people to edit. The columns that don't have this set or have ReadOnly set to false are editable by the user when in edit mode.

Comment: can you please help me with thi sone! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654434/solution-for-selecting-and-editing-data-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 3):

If you use a     SqlDataSource then you should make sure to remove the columns to update from the UpdateCommand in the      SqlDataSource if not you will have a problem when you update the fields

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set ReadOnly on DataGridViewCell.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.readonly.aspx

```
gridView.Rows[rowIndex][colName].ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Added an example, not that it wasn't self explanatory anyway.

Comment: can you please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655124/asp-net-updating-database-with-checkboxes

Comment: @I__ - Please mark one of the answers you have been given as the correct one, by using the tick on the left.