# solution for selecting AND editing data at the same time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have an asp.net application in c#.

i have a table in a sql server database with two fields:

```
Field1
Comments
```

i need to allow the user to SELECT the `Field1` and add comments for that specific `Field1`

the user would then post the input back to the server

how do i accomplish this? which control can i use? is there already a simple jquery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely depends on your site setup. However if you have a list of Field1 values and put them in a DropDownList, you'll be able to select one and add a comment in a box.

This also heavily depends on your user interface / workflows. This is just one of MANY possible ways to do this.

Code front

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlField1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Value1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlRecord" runat="server"
    InsertCommand="InsertRecord" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Field1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind

```
public void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Do your validation of the data here
  ..

  // Add fields and insert
  sqlRecord.InsertParameters["Field1"].DefaultValue = ddlField1.SelectedValue;
  sqlRecord.InsertParameters["Comment"].DefaultValue = tbComment.Text;
  sqlRecord.Insert();
}
```

This is untested and partial pseudo code but should get you in the right direction for a general non-MVC web app. Also this doesn't use any JavaScript / jQuery, just ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: can you please help wtih this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655124/asp-net-updating-database-with-checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

I would put the possible selections in a drop down, then use jquery to make a JSON request to get the data from your controller, then have a save button which calls another javascript function to post the modified data back to the controller.

controller:

```
public ActionResult GetFields()
{
var model=new MyModel();
model.Selections =(from m in database.table select m.Field1).ToList();
return View(model);
}

public ActionResult GetComments(string field1)
{
return Content((from c in database.table where(c.Field1==field1)select c.Comments).First());
}

[HttpPost]
public void SaveComments(string field1, string comments)
{
var record=(from r in database.table where(r.Field1==field1)select r).First();
record.Comments=comments;
database.SaveChanges;
return;
}
```

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function SaveComments(){
var url='@Url.Action("GetComments","YourControllerName");
url+='?field1='+$('#selections option:selected').text();
$('#selectedField').text($('#selections option:selected').text());
$('#commentEditor').load(url);
};

function SaveComments(){
var url='@Url.Action("SaveComments","YourControllerName")';
url+='?field1='+$('#selections option:selected').text()+'&comments='+$('#commentEditor').text();
$('#dummy').load(url);
};
</script>

<select id="selections" onchange="SelectionChanged()">
@foreach(var item in Model.Selections)
{
<option value="@item">@item</option>
}
</select>
<div id="selectedField"/>
<input type="text" id="commentEditor"/>
<input type="button" value="apply" onclick="SaveComments()"/>
<div id="dummy"/>
```

Disclaimer: There may be small errors in this (don't normally write large chunks of code in a text box :P), you should probably not use the dummy div, and you will need to have on your view model a List whose get returns based on the values in Selections.  This should give you the general idea though.

Comment: oops sorry, not my expertise there, perhaps someone wil convert it for you, but hopefully you can understand the theory of what I've done and apply it to your own project.  It was never meant to be a cut and paste code block :)