# updating database with checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have a datagrid and every row has a checkbox on it. also every field in every row can be updated

the user can update multiple rows and check any checkboxes.

at the click of the SUBMIT button all the data should be updated. i need the checkboxes to update a boolean (or what ever the bool type is for sql server) in a database.

1. how do implement the checkboxes to be able to update the table in the DB?
2. with the click of the submit button how do i get all the data to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the datagrid and store all of the data that you want to update in arrays or the like. Sql server has a `bit` datatype and you can set it to `0` if the checkbox is off or `1` if it is `checked`. Once you collect all the data pass it to your data layer for a sql update

You can use the `DataGrid` object to iterate through its cells/controls. For example, using a nested loop you can do:

```
myDG.Items[index1].Cells[index2].Controls[0]
```

**Edit**: It depends on the input controls you have in the columns because you have to cast them. Say you have a datagrid with 10 columns and TextBoxes in all columns except the last, which is CheckBox, you would do:

```
CheckBox cb = null;
TextBox tb = null;
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
for(int row = 0; row < myDG.Items.Count; row++)
{
  for(int col = 0; col < myDG.Columns.Count; col++)
  {
    if(col < 9){
      tb = myDG.Items[row].Cells[col].Controls[0] as TextBox;
      myList.Add(tb.Text);
    }
    else{
      cb = myDG.Items[row].Cells[col].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
      myList.Add(((cb.Checked) ? "1" : "0"));
    }
  }
}
```

You could use a 2D array/list to store if you wanted too. HTH

Comment: sorry but can you give an example of the aspx html code as well

Comment: why? It would just be a datagrid with 10 columns, or 0 if they're not bound and automatically generated

Comment: this is a REALLY smart solution im going to try it out

Comment: i guess i have to take a step back. im fine with displaying data from a db into a gridview; however, i do not know how to change the gridview to have textboxes instead of "labels" for the columns, do you know how?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were already using textboxes and such. How do you allow users to edit the *gridview* (I thought we were talking about a *datagrid* via post) directly using labels? Anyway, I believe you would have to look into the following: `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><!--asp:textbox here--></ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4076/discussion-between-i-and-shredder)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a GridView, building on the example from a previous example you got, you can do this. ** this is semi-pseudo code, beware**

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    autogenerateeditbutton="true"
    allowpaging="true" 
    datakeynames="CustomerID"  
    runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:templatefield>
         <itemtemplate> <%-- This is itemtemplate so they are visible by default --%>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbVerify" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CustomerID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
         </itemtemplate>
      </asp:templatefield>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" readonly="true" headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" readonly="true" headertext="Customer Name"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="ZIP Code"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>

<asp:Button ID="btSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Code behind to process this

```
public void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow row in CustomersGridView.Rows) 
  {
    CheckBox cbVerify = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbVerify");
    HiddenField hidID = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hidID");

    // Do your validation of the data here
    ..

    if (cbVerify != null)
    {
      // Add fields and update
      sqlRecord.UpdateParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = hidID.Value;
      sqlRecord.UpdateParameters["Valid"].DefaultValue = cbVerify.Checked.ToString();
      sqlRecord.Update();
    }
}
```

This should get you in a specific direction to look.

Comment: thank you so much for your great help what is the purpose of the hidden field?

Comment: The hidden field makes it simpler to get the ID of the record so that way you can update it. It's mot mandatory since you can use the **row** object to get the key, but it's just easier is all.